# Difficulty working with string binary search in java - search key not found in the list

Tags: java, string, search, binary, full-text-search

I have been try to use a searck key to get a value in this binary search program. If I put "CCC" as one of the elements and try to search for the it using the search parameter, it fetches successfully but when I remove "CCC" from the list of elements and changes the search key to any of the other elements, it does not fetch any result.

```
static String[] books = {
            "Rome", "King Arthur", "The Johnson's", "Romeo and Juliet", "Hoodlums", "Baptist",
            "Rogue", "Marc Anthony", "The survivor", "Arc of Grace", "France", "Holy",
            "Mayor", "Fatality", "Immortal", "Fidelity", "The Major", "In the Hood"
    };
    static int min = 0;
    static int max = books.length - 1;
    static int mid;
    static String key = "Rome";

    public static int stringBinarySearch() {
        while (min <= max) {
            mid = (min + max) / 2;
            if (books[mid].compareTo(key) < 0) {
                min = mid + 1;
            }
            else if (books[mid].compareTo(key) > 0) {
                max = mid - 1;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Book found and available at shelve ");
                return mid;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Book not found");
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(stringBinarySearch());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search requires the array to be sorted.

Since the array isn't sorted, you're better off doing a linear search, or if you will be searching frequently, then sort the array (using `Arrays.sort(books)`) and then you can use your binary search method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use a binary search algorithm your data set must be sorted by search condition.

In this example, you are comparing by string of `books`  then the `books` must be sorted in a-z order first.